# Not able to find what is the syntax error in the code?

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
def makeInverseIndex(strlist):
 return { s:{ j if strlist[i] in strlist[j].split() for j in range(len(strlist)) } 
        for (i,s) in enumerate(strlist) }
```

What is the syntax error in the code in Python??

Comment: You don't actually need `i`; `strlist[i]` could be replaced with `s`, so you could drop the `enumerate` and just iterate over `strlist` in the outer comprehension.

Comment: Similarly, you could replace the range-len with an enumerate, producing `{s: {i for i, s2 in enumerate(strlist) if s in s2.split()} for s in strlist}`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have an `if` statement to the left of `for` inside any comprehension unless you also have an `else` part (ternary operator). You need to move `if strlist[i] in strlist[j].split()` to the right,

```
def makeInverseIndex(strlist):
    return {s:{j for j in range(len(strlist)) if strlist[i] in strlist[j].split()}
            for (i,s) in enumerate(strlist)}
```